# jQuery PATCH request not recognised by Marvin.JsonPatch

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, json-patch

I'm trying to send an AJAX PATCH request to a Web API method and have the patched object recognised by [Marvin.JsonPatch](https://github.com/KevinDockx/JsonPatch).

So far, everything I've sent to the server has resulted in an empty request being received.

The Web API controller method looks like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult Update(ElementType elementType,
                                long elementId,
                                [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<TranslationMatchDiscounts> matchDiscountsPatch)
```

And that `TranslationMatchDiscounts` object is very straightforward:

```
public class TranslationMatchDiscounts
{
    public double ContextMatches { get; set; }


    public long ElementId { get; set; }


    public Enumerations.ElementType ElementType { get; set; }


    public double ExactMatches { get; set; }


    public double PerfectMatches { get; set; }


    public double Repetitions { get; set; }
}
```

And my jQuery AJAX request is put together like this:

```
$.ajax({
    //contentType: "application/json",
    data: { "Repetitions": 0.15 },
    //data: JSON.stringify({ "Repetitions": 0.15 }),
    dataType: "json",
    //processData: false,
    method: "PATCH",
    url: // my URL
});
```

The commented-out properties show some things I've tried.

The controller does get hit, that's not the problem, and the "Repetitions" property is being sent but the server-side `JsonPatchDocument<TranslationMatchDiscounts>` parameter is either...

- `null` if I leave the `contentType` property in-place
- has no properties/updates for all other attempts

What is the correct way to send a PATCH request using jQuery's .ajax()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My fault. I was under the impression that PATCH allowed us to post an object with only the changed properties, *i.e.*...

```
{
    "Repetitions": 0.15
}
```

No. What PATCH requires is a *[JSON patch document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-3)*. According to the RTF:

> A JSON Patch document is a JSON [[RFC4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627)] document that represents an
> array of objects.

So my example should really be

```
var patchDoc = [ { "op": "replace", "path": "/Repetitions", "value": 0.15 } ];

$.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(patchDoc),
    dataType: "json",
    method: "PATCH",
    url: // my URL
});
```